# DockerCLI error on Win Server 2016: "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, docker-desktop

I'm trying to use Docker on Windows Server 2016, before I do that I need tell Docker to use Linux containers. I've been trying to achieve this via the command `./DockerCli.exe -SwitchLinuxEngine` but I'm getting the error:

```
Unable to create: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 127
at Get-NetAdapter<End>, <No file>: line 181
at New-Switch, <No file>: line 127
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 411
```

I also have the same error when trying to start Docker Desktop, is there somewhere I can alter to fix this?

Thank you.